# where to download xamp server for 64 bit windows 7 system

Tags: download, xampp

I was trieng to download xampp server for my 64 bit machine. But in [apachefriends.org](https://www.apachefriends.org/de/download.html) site I am not getting 64 bit version. I wanted to check whether 32 bit version will work fine in 64 bit or not. And also kindly suggest if u know any link to download 64 bit version of xamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32-bit XAMPP works well on a 64bit machine but has RAM limitations. I was unable to find a 64-bit XAMPP but there's a Windows equivalent called WAMP. You can download it from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver). 
It is 64 bit.